# How to move shared Rails model behavior into mixins?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have two models that are almost identical. I would like to create one or more mixins so that I can share the behavior between these models. Here's en example model which includes every variation I can think of:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_OPTIONS = ['new', 'approved', 'rejected', 'deleted']
  attr_accessible :status
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => STATUS_OPTIONS

  def self.custom_finder(status)
    find_by_status(status)
  end

  def simple_instance_method
    'easy'
  end
end
```

I understand some of the basics of including instance methods from a Ruby module, but I'm confused when it comes to more advanced things like ActiveRecord class methods, constants, etc.

```
module ModelClassMethods
  def custom_finder(status)
    find_by_status(status)
  end
end

module ModelInstanceMethods
  def simple_instance_method
    'easy'
  end
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_OPTIONS = ['new', 'approved', 'rejected', 'deleted']
  attr_accessible :status
  validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => STATUS_OPTIONS

  extend ModelClassMethods
  include ModelInstanceMethods
end
```

Now how do I extract the constant and validation method?

Answer (score 0):

Constants are included with `include` and the family of `validates` methods are also instance methods so...

```
module ModelInstanceMethods
  STATUS_OPTIONS = ['new', 'approved', 'rejected', 'deleted']

  def simple_instance_method
    'easy'
  end
end
```

Till here you are OK. I think the answer is [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Comment: Those validation methods are instance methods? I thought they were class methods because they apply to all instances of a class.

Comment: I'm not a rails source-code guru, but check this: `ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods.select { |m| m.to_s =~ /validates/ }`

Comment: I'm running into an issue with `attr_accessible` which I think will be the same issue I will experience when putting the `validates` methods in a module...when you require the module, the `attr_accessible` class method cannot be found because it's trying to apply it when defining the module.

Comment: Switching to concerns helped a little. Ultimately it's just syntactic sugar for what I was trying to do. The documentation gives an example of using `class_eval` which would have fixed the issue. I ran into an issue with constants because I defined them in a different module. I just needed to call them using the namespace of the model class: `Model::STATUS_OPTIONS` instead of just `STATUS_OPTIONS`